# I want to pause current playing audio when another audio start

Tags: javascript, dom, audio

I have an web application when click the artist image that plays audio files.
I'm pretty new to this. I found a few solutions on the internet, but I couldn't do it.
I want to pause current playing audio when another audio start.but it continues to play in the background , but what I want is to pause and continuing playing from that point forward. So far, I could not make that change.

```
function switchCase(key){
    switch (key) {
        case 'mozart-img':
            var audio = new Audio("sounds/mozart.mp3")
            audio.play();
            break;
        case 'beethoven-img':
            var audio = new Audio("sounds/beethoven.mp3")
            audio.play();
            break;
        case 'chopin-img':
            var audio = new Audio("sounds/chopin.mp3")
            audio.play();
            break;
        case 'schumann-img':
            var audio = new Audio("sounds/schumann.mp3")
            audio.play();
            break;                
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess I didn't express it well. My English is not very good. If track 1 is playing and I play track 2 , track 1 should completely stop. then I start track 3? track 2 also completely stop. Only the song I selected at that moment should play others must be reset.

Comment: no, you expressed it just fine - I was asking what to do in the circumstances I outlined - I thought once track 2 finishes, track 1 resumes - sorry, I totally misinterpreted what *pause and continuing playing from that point forward* meant - my bad, comment removed

Comment: This is for dom - exercise  I just made it up. https://github.com/bkaya0897/sbatufy   you can take a look here.

Comment: https://bkaya0897.github.io/sbatufy/

Comment: yes, and the answer below will do it

Comment: it didnt work. even though i edited it. because the playing song, namely the object, cannot be found. beethon_img_audio.pause(); for example it says beethon_img_audio not defined.

Comment: yeah, that answer is wrong, since it creates a new Audio object each time you call the function

Comment: If I can assign the currently playing song on the page to variable with DOM
then the variable.pause() seems to be resolved but how.

Comment: nothing in the code you posted has anything to do with DOM - not sure why you keep mentioning the dom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an IIFE here so no globals will be required (other than the function `switchCase` which you have already anyway)

```
const switchCase = (function() {
    let playing;
    function stop() {
        if (playing) {
            playing.removeEventListener('ended', stop); //*
            playing.pause();
            playing = null;
        }
    }
    return function (key){
        stop();
        switch (key) {
            case 'mozart-img':
                playing = new Audio("sounds/mozart.mp3");
                break;
            case 'beethoven-img':
                playing = new Audio("sounds/beethoven.mp3");
                break;
            case 'chopin-img':
                playing = new Audio("sounds/chopin.mp3");
                break;
            case 'schumann-img':
                playing = new Audio("sounds/schumann.mp3");
                break;                
            default:
                break;
        }
        playing.play();
        playing.addEventListener('ended', stop); //*
    };
})();
```

So, playing holds the currently playing audio object - before creating a new one, simply stop the currently playing one (if it exists)

Added "ended" event handler - probably overkill, but just remove the lines with `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` (marked with //* ) to get rid of probably redundant event handling